# A div at the bottom of a page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a popup bar at the bottom of the screen, the popup bar appears but it covers the bottom of the screen.I have the `div` under the other `div` but it still covers the bottom of the page

I want the bar to be at the bottom of the browser window but not to cover the bottom of the page when the person scrolls to the bottom.

Edit: I want the bar to stay at the bottom of the **screen**, by removing fixed or changing it to relative will place it at the bottom of the **page.**

I want this div bar only to appear on one page, its a module for a CMS, I need the #bar to be the last div on the page.

Changing the position: will not help because I also want the bar to also scroll on the page.

I don't want the to have to a 100px space on the bottom of all the other pages

### HTML:

```
<!-- main div -->
<div id="master">

</div>

<!-- bar div -->
<div id="bar">

</div>
```

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#bar').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);

});
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3vYGS/1/)

Comment: Pad the bottom of the body? `body { padding-bottom: 60px; }`. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/3vYGS/3/) That what you mean?

Comment: Set the #bar div position: auto;

Comment: set #bar position to relative not fixed. or add padding/margin bottom of the #master as large as #bar's height.

Comment: None of the above are a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

try `margin-bottom:100px;` to the id `#master`

here is the jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/banded_krait/3vYGS/7/

**EDIT:**

if you want to make it in all pages of your website than you have to put margin or padding to the body tag of your page and that will solve your problem and it will work in every page. :)

```
body{
   margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

Comment: It is only to effect one page not the whole website, the master div was only used as an example.

Comment: @JohnnyQ Did you even look at my comment? I solved this as soon as you put it up lol.

Comment: @JohnnyQ Also just add a div to the bottom of that page then. And use that to put a `margin` or `padding`. Or just include the `CSS` on that page. Really not hard.

Comment: as @Ruddy said, than you have to put margin or padding to the body tag of your page and that will solve your problem and it will work in every page. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Just replace this**

```
#master {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px; 
    width:95%;margin:30 auto; 
    border-color: blue; 
    margin-bottom:70px;
    //height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3vYGS/2/).
I've changed:

```
#bar{
  right:0;
  width:60%;
}
```

Comment: No I need the bar to go across the page 100%, I don't think your solution would work well most websites

Comment: Than you have to remove `position: fixed`. [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3vYGS/4/)

Comment: I want the bar to stay at the bottom of the screen and be able to scroll, by removing position fixed at the it stays at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/47AdA/).
Just change `position` to `relative`.

Comment: I want the bar to stay at the bottom of the screen and be able to scroll, by removing position fixed at the it stays at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3vYGS/8/)

```
margin-bottom:14%; in #master
```